# form components missing from design view but present in the designer.cs code in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project that has a lot of code in the C# portion, the XX.Designer.cs file, but in the design view where we have a visual representation of what the UI should look like, the form is blank, although there is still a form there, and when I hit play and debug, the form is also blank.  Any ideas please on some potential causes?

Comment: Take a look in the Document Outline view, and traverse the tree to the item that you think you should be able to see.  Look for any likely suspects in the properties grid for that item.  Now check the output console for any obvious error messages.

Comment: Check the errors pane, may be there is an error on the designer file.